# Windows: How to delay the output of a screen?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, nvidia-geforce

We need to delay the output of a screen.

We have two screens connected to the same PC (**NVIDIA video card**) and we basically need to put a delay of 5 seconds to the other screen: whatever we're doing on the first screen **must be delayed on the second screen**.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

NVIDIA GTX 950
Windows 10 Pro 64 bit

Comment: It sounds very impractical to want this, so I can only think that it could be done by using a camera and showing its output on the second screen. But even then, it would more likely be like 1 or 2 seconds depending on the specs of the camera, not 5.

Comment: The point is I can do it in Linux (there's a simple way). Now I need to do it in Windows as well.

Comment: Well, I have made a little software to workaround on this but it's really slow, it basically clones the primary screen to a form, then I put the form on the second screen and everything I see is delayed by 5 seconds: http://pastebin.com/LG8qnnyp (forgot to delete line 23 and 3).

Comment: Imma bump this. I need this bcs songsterr.com doesnt provide a method for delaying the screen output. I just need to increase the delay on my screen precisely, like if i moved the mouse and on screen it moves 150ms later.

Answer (score 1):

Recently we had a project for a client that required delaying the broadcast by 30 seconds so they could "bleep" out bad words and we found there are two ways. We went with OBS

1. The easiest way to accomplish this seemingly is to use third-party video capture software that includes a "delay" or "latency" feature. For example, OBS Studio is a popular option used to live streaming, it also can record and playback with delay.
2. In the enterprise or professional environment, there are other hardware-based solutions i.e. delay line or time shift servers, these are mainly used in broadcast applications. But those are costlier and more complex to set up, depending on your need the OBS may be good a starter.

Comment: That sounds like a good attempt but i have really low quality when doing that. The reso is correct, the bitrate aswell and i use a 2060 OC 12GB and i dont know what the issue is

Comment: @Noblockhit OBS Settings: Double-check your OBS settings, specifically the output settings. Make sure the encoder is set to use your GPU (NVENC if you're using an NVIDIA card) and that the preset is set to a quality level that matches your needs.
System Resources:  monitor your CPU and GPU usage while streaming. If either is maxed out, you may need to adjust settings to reduce the load.

Test Different Bitrates: ,the issue might be related to the network's ability to handle the chosen bitrate.
Network Issues:  A slow or unstable connection can lead to quality issues.

Answer (score 0):

This post is similar to the post
[How to Mirror my first monitor onto my second monitor but with a DELAY](https://superuser.com/questions/1583076/how-to-mirror-my-first-monitor-onto-my-second-monitor-but-with-a-delay). I quote below the accepted answer:

> You can do this OBS (Open Broadcast Studio). Once your scene/input is
> set to your game, you can then add a few delay filters to it (right
> click on source --> add filter --> source delay). Then, you need to
> set the output in OBS to use a custom URL in the advanced output
> settings with ffmpeg. You will get a URL similar to
> (udp://ipaddress:2222). You can then download VLC Media Player and
> open a network stream using that URL on your second monitor.
>
> [Source 1: adding delay filter](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/adding-an-8-seconds-delay.106893/)
>
> [Source 2: obs thread on streaming to local vlc instance](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/stream-directly-to-vlc-mplayer-is-it-possible.53918/)
>
> [Source 3: ffmpeg point to point streaming](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#Pointtopointstreaming)

Comment: Why are you not voting to close as a duplicate?

Comment: @DavidPostill: How can I with a bounty? I can only come back when the bounty is over.