# How to Mirror my first monitor onto my second monitor but with a DELAY

Tags: multiple-monitors, gaming, delay

I'm trying to take the display from my first monitor and also display it on my second monitor but with a **3-5 second delay**. I don't mind if it just mirrors one application.

The purpose would be when I'm playing a game I would like to look over to my second monitor and examine what happened. I don't really have any clue of how one would go about this.

Comment: 3-5 seconds with 60 Hz refresh rate is 180-300 frames delay, that's a significant amount of information to store somewhere between your computer and monitor. I'm not sure whether there's an easy solution for that.

Comment: Perhaps if you use an NVIDIA graphics card, then Instant Replay available with the Geforce driver (at least on my 1660 Ti, I don't know what card you use) lets you record to disk constantly and then when you hit the shortcut alt f10,  it saves the last few minutes to your Videos. I strongly recommend you use a RAMdisk for this as you don't want lots of writes per second going on on your hard drive, or even worse, your SSD. I use this for gaming and set a 1.5 GB ramdisk and it captures 2 minutes 45 seconds worth of footage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this OBS (Open Broadcast Studio). Once your scene/input is set to your game, you can then add a few delay filters to it (right click on source --> add filter --> source delay). Then, you need to set the output in OBS to use a custom URL in the advanced output settings with ffmpeg. You will get a URL similar to (udp://ipaddress:2222). You can then download VLC Media Player and open a network stream using that URL on your second monitor.

[Source 1: adding delay filter](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/adding-an-8-seconds-delay.106893/)

[Source 2: obs thread on streaming to local vlc instance](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/stream-directly-to-vlc-mplayer-is-it-possible.53918/)

[Source 3: ffmpeg point to point streaming](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#Pointtopointstreaming)

Answer (score 1):

Implementing a delay requires a *FIFO buffer* https://helloacm.com/how-do-you-design-a-circular-fifo-buffer-queue-in-c/

Data enters the buffer at one end and moves along until it reaches the other.

You can implement a buffer in software, in hardware, spatially or via a buffered network.

**Software**

You would have to run a process alongside the game so they would be sharing processor time. If the delay program cannot hook into the game code then it would have to use interrupts to read graphics memory.  It would then take snapshots of the memory and store them in RAM. If you have plenty of RAM to spare after the game has loaded this may be possible. The same program then sends the delayed picture through a different output port to the other monitor.

**Hardware**

You could implement an electronic delay in hardware that you insert in the cable  but that hardware would need its own processor and memory. It would be a microprocessor that would have to be programmed.

**Spatial**

If you could direct a laser to a reflector on the moon that then came back to you, you could get a total delay of 1.3 + 1.3 = 2.6 seconds.

If you send the signal to an artificial satellite and back, you can use the built in buffers of the network have in place. Provided the bandwidth of the satellite is never overloaded then you will get a constant delay.  Think of news reporters calling from overseas by satellite phone, thus making it difficult to hold a normal conversation.

**Network**

The internet is jam-packed with buffering at all speeds. For example if you leave your phone switched off for a week, when you come back you will still be able to see the text messages you have missed. The problem with delays on the internet is that it is very difficult to gain precise control of them.

**Recommendation**

If this is a single-player game that doesn't have a replay facility then I believe there is software out there that you can purchase that will allow screenshots and even replays.  You may wish to search online for these.

If you don't want to analyse what happened immediately but later at your leisure then again I would search for 3rd party software. It will do the buffering (and storing on disk) for you.

Unless you can buy software or hardware off the shelf, you are going to have to do it yourself. It would be a great achievement (and fantastic for you CV) but expect to spend the next few months implementing a buffer instead of playing the game!